# Dynamically allocate memory for static variable in classes

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding how to allocate memory dynamically for static variables in a class.
Consider this example

```
class my_class {
    static int *ptr_to_int;
    // Don't care 
};
```

How to allocate memory for ptr_to_int?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with the fact that it's a pointer? Could you do it if it's a plain old `int`?

Comment: The same way you allocate dynamic memory for any other variable: using `new` or `new[]`. Is there a specific reason why those mechanisms won't work for you?

Answer (score 2):

In a single implementation file:

```
int* my_class::ptr_to_int = new int;
```

But **why**? Do you **really** need a pointer? What's wrong with just

```
class my_class {
    static int actual_int;
    // Don't care 
};
```

Comment: Thanks, no real reason. I was thinking on how to initialize a static pointer and couldn't think of it. Also it is not restricted for int* if it was huge structure then I would not like to allocate memory until first instance is created(Makes no sense though). I don't have a use case for that.

Answer (score 0):

The class name here works merely as a scope name for your purpose. Just using my_class::ptr_to_int as a static pointer.